# How can I replace tokens in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

```
I have a json object

    const item = {
fooUrl : 'www.google.com',
fooDomain : 'www.yahoo.com'
}
```

and an input string `foo$ENV[fooDomain]bar`. I want to replace the `$ENV[fooDomain]` with `item.fooDomain` and similarly for `accountsUrl`,
I want this to happen dynamically meaning even if a new unknown key is added the pattern should find and replace `$ENV[something]` value.

What I have done till now

```
console.log(str.replace(/(?:^|\s)$ENV[(\w*)](.*?)(?:\s|$)/g,item.accountsUrl // how to make this dynamic ?));
```

Comment: use a callback as an argument: `replace(...., ($0, $1) => items[$1]`

Comment: `str.replace(/\$ENV\[([^\][]*)]/g, (m,x) => item[x] || m)`? Why do you use whitespace boundaries `(?:^|\s)` and `(?:\s|$)` if your string with an expected match has no whitespace on both ends of the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a match and a single capture group to get the property name that corresponds with the object.

Note that you have to escape the dollar sign and the openings square bracket.

As @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) points out in the comments, you can use `|| m` to return the match in case the group 1 value can not be found in the object.

```js
const item = {
  accountsUrl: 'www.google.com',
  accountsDomain: 'www.yahoo.com'
}
const regex = /\$ENV\[(\w+)]/
let s = "foo$ENV[accountsDomain]bar";
s = s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => item[g1] || m);
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
str.replace(/(?<=\$ENV\[)[^\]]+/, match => item[match]);
```