# How to replace string only if the replacement exists in the target object?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have the following snippet from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953302/how-can-i-replace-tokens-in-string), this code replaces the token `$ENV[accountsDomain]` in a string with the key from `item` object `accountsDomain: 'www.yahoo.com'` and similarly for `accountsUrl`

how can I run replace conditionally, replace the string only if `item[g1]` exists, as these keys are optional

```js
const item = {
  accountsUrl: 'www.google.com',
  accountsDomain: 'www.yahoo.com'
}
const regex = /\$ENV\[(\w+)]/
let s = "foo$ENV[accountsDomain]bar";
s = s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => item[g1] || m);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: If `item[g1]` is undefined, the match is returned. Is that not the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in replace, you have to do it outside.

```js
const item = {
  accountsUrl: 'www.google.com',
  accountsDomain: 'www.yahoo.com'
}

function replaceItem(item, key) {
  const regex = /\$ENV\[(\w+)]/
  let s = `foo$ENV[${key}]bar`;
  let [, match] = s.match(regex);
  return item[match] && s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => item[g1]);
}

console.log('result with existing key:', replaceItem(item, 'accountsDomain'))
console.log('result with un-existing key:', replaceItem(item, 'accDomain'))
```